# How to render components in a nested route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have sandbox below:

[image: Edit Responsive - antd@4.16.3 (forked)]

Currently top level navigation is working as expected however when I try to nest `sub routes` it wont render my `Item1` component. Is there something I'm missing. I tried to wrap Item in nav3 path but that did not work either.

```
  <Layout>
        <Header
          className="site-layout-sub-header-background"
          style={{ padding: 0 }}
        />
        <Content style={{ margin: "24px 16px 0" }}>
          <div
            className="site-layout-background"
            style={{ padding: 24, minHeight: 360 }}
          >
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/nav1" component={nav1} />
              <Route path="/nav2" component={nav2} />
              <Route path="/nav3" component={nav3} />
              <Route path="/nav3/item1" component={item1} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Content>
        <Footer style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
          Ant Design ©2018 Created by Ant UED
        </Footer>
      </Layout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just add `exact` in `Route`:

```
<Route exact path="/nav3" component={nav3} />
<Route exact path="/nav3/item1" component={item1} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `exact={true}` prop to your `/nav3` route like below.

```
<Route path="/nav3" component={nav3} exact={true}/>
```

If you don't add `exact` to your `Route` component, every url that starts with `/nav3` will render the `nav3` component.

> `exact: bool`
> When true, will only match if the path matches the
> location.pathname exactly.

You can read more about the exact prop [here](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/exact-bool)